# Fetch all text from text file and show in UserForm text box

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the code below which reads the text from a text file and places all of the text in my UserForm text box. The problem I have is when the text is shown in the textbox it shows unformatted, i.e. text divided by line breaks like:

```
The cat went east
The dog went south
```

all reads on one line and has these weird 'P' symbols in amongst the text like:

```
'P'The cat went east 'P'The dog went south'P'
```

So one of my questions is how do I restore the formatting of the text to display like this?:

```
    The cat went east
    The dog went south
```

And eventually my text is going to be cut off out of view of the text box because the text box is only so big but my text could be multiple lines like:

```
The cat went east
The dog went south
The cat went east
The dog went south
The cat went east
The dog went south
The cat went east
The dog went south
```

So how can I add  scroll up/down function to the text box?

Code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

  m1 = Month(Range("C" & ActiveCell.Row).Value)
M = MonthName(m1, True)
Y = Year(Range("C" & ActiveCell.Row).Value)

Dim Total As String
Dim FilePath As String
Dim strLine As String
FilePath = "\\MI-FILESERVE1\Shared Folders\Shared_Business_Dev\Tenders\" & Range("G" & ActiveCell.Row).Value & "\" & Range("E" & ActiveCell.Row).Value & "\" & Range("F" & ActiveCell.Row).Value & " - " & M & " - " & Y & "\log.txt"
Open FilePath For Input As #1
While EOF(1) = False
    'read the next line of data in the text file
    Line Input #1, strLine
    Total = Total & vbNewLine & strLine
    'increment the row counter
    i2 = i2 + 1
Wend
Close #1

TextBox1 = Total
End Sub
```

Comment: I believe what you are talking about are called *pilcrows* and are intended to note the end of a paragraph. ¶ Perhaps you have RTF (Rich Text Format) set. I do find it a little odd that there is one at the beginning of the text string. Replace Chr(182) with vbCrLf.

Comment: @Jeeped, I'm not using Chr(182) anywhere in my script though?

Comment: Seems as if the `TextBox1` is not in `MultiLine` mode. Put `TextBox1.MultiLine = True` before `TextBox1 = Total`.

Comment: @AxelRichter thanks this solved the issue. Do you happen to know how I can make the text box scrollable also? thanks

Comment: Try using the help with keyword `TextBox`. Or simply type `TextBox1.` and look which possible properties and methods where listed then. `TextBox1.ScrollBars = fmScrollBarsVertical`

Answer (score 1):

If a `TextBox` is not in `MultiLine` mode, then line breaks will be showed as ¶.

You can set the `TextBox` in `MultiLine` mode using the property `MultiLine`:

`TextBox1.MultiLine = True`

To get a list of all possible properties and methods of a `TextBox` try using the help with keyword `TextBox`. Or simply type `TextBox1.` and look which possible properties and methods were listed then.